# Detecting rectangular corners with python cv2

Tags: python, opencv, omr

I'm trying to implement an optical mark-recognition with python opencv. As part of the program, I used a pre-"filter" to transform the original image into a binary one and then use contour detection. At first glance, the binary images looks great, but when applying the contour detection on some images it works and on others it doesn't (even though they are really similar).

first this is the python code for the preprocessing "filters":

```py
def PreProcessing(img):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    ret, imgThresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    return imgThresh
```

Second, the function for finding the corners:

```py
def findCorners(canny):
    contourCounter = 0
    points1 = []
    points2 = []
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for cnt in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if area > 400000 and area < 2500000:
            epsilon = 0.001 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, epsilon, True)
            for point in approx:
                x, y = point[0]
                if contourCounter == 0:
                    points1.append((x, y))
                elif contourCounter == 1:
                    points2.append((x, y))
            contourCounter += 1
    if contourCounter != 2:
        raise Exception(f"the number of big contours detacted is {contourCounter}")
    return points1 , points2
```

Here are two images by way of example:

One that works:

original
[image: original]

result
[image: result]

and one that doesn't:

original
[image: original]

result
[image: result]

Comment: You could also look for lines using hough transforms then calculate their intersection points. You can do some edge detection with Sobel rather. Keep us posted! :)

Comment: Also, it will never be perfect - maybe look at 10 or even 100 and see how your algorithm performs statistically. Like any model it will always get it wrong sometimes. opencv is great but there are a lot of tunable parameters that make it hard to generalize. Nice problem!

Comment: Also last point: you need to invent a precise definition of "works" - a quantitative metric if possible

Comment: Canny edge detection is often a poor idea. Can you try adaptive thresholding instead ?

Comment: @jtlz2 a works situation will be 16 points representing the corners of the boxes (I got it as a list)

Comment: @YvesDaoust can you please expand a little bit or give an exemple?

Comment: Lookup adaptive thresholding in OpenCV.

Comment: Remove the thick black lines first.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77032956/cv2-rectangular-detecting-issue/77034412#77034412